# How do I do a 'group by' for a datetime when I want to group by just the date?

Tags: mysql

That's a really awkward title :)

I need to write a report that generates a list of declines by date.  The date is store as a datetime field and is returning the number of declines by datetime.

Here's my SQL:

```
select ps.date_scheduled, count(*) from payments_schedule ps
left join invoices i on i.invoice_id=ps.invoice_id
left join orders o on o.order_id=i.order_id
where ps.date_scheduled>'2009-06-01 00:00:00'
group by ps.date_scheduled
```

2009-06-25 14:13:04 1
2009-06-25 14:13:07 1
..etc...

Not cool.  What I want is this:
2009-06-25 25
2009-06-26 31
etc...

How do I do that?  Thanks :)

Comment: Convert the datetime to date and then group by the date column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  CAST(ps.date_scheduled AS DATE), COUNT(*)
FROM    payments_schedule ps
LEFT JOIN
        invoices i
ON      i.invoice_id = ps.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN
        orders o
ON      o.order_id = i.order_id
WHERE   ps.date_scheduled > '2009-06-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
        CAST(ps.date_scheduled AS DATE)
```

Comment: Quass - is CAST more efficient than DATE()?

Comment: @Paolo: no, they're complete synonyms. I prefer this syntax to avoid confusion with DAY() which returns the day of month.

Answer (score 4):

```
GROUP BY DATE(ps.date_scheduled)
```

Comment: This is what I tend to use, although I've never benchmarked it. Not sure if MySQL uses an index (if available) for this or if it re-calculates each record's DATE() every time. If it re-calculates, a new column might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to `select DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, ps.date_scheduled))`.  This will preserve only the date portion of the date-time.  You will also need to group by the same expression.

**EDIT**: This is how to solve the problem for SQL Server.